# How to script the install of openam

Tags: openam

According to the above documentation, to create the initial configuration I need to open a web browser. This is sound really weird to me. I would like to script the deploy of OpenAM and it seems impossible.

https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Deploy+OpenAM

My actual script do the following

1. Download openam
2. extract openam
3. copy .war in tomcat webapp
4. extract administration tools
5. extract configuration tool
6. extract diagnostic tool
7. download opendj
8. lauch the setup of opendj with all args

Now I would like to launch the configuration tool of openam with the configuration file I would like to use but it seems OpenAM must be already configured;

The configuration tool require `$HOME/openam/boostrap` file where `$HOME/openam` is the configuration folder that should exists once you have already configure it.

Is this true ? To use configuration tool you must already have configured your service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not ... 'configurator tool' is meant to initially configure OpenAM.

For the sake of simplicity, you should not use an external data store.

If you really want to use an external configuration store (OpenDJ or Oracle DSEE are the only supported ones currently), the external config store must be up and running before launching 'configurator tool'.

OpenDJ can be configurated in an automated way as well.

If you do not need an external configuration store, just deploy the OpenAM web-app and use 'configurator tool'

Comment: Any changes in the current scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Some helpful links:

- [Using the CLI](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Using+the+CLI#UsingtheCLI-CLI)
- [configurator.jar documentation](http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/reference/index/man-configurator-jar-1.html)
- [Automated installation and configuration of OpenAM](http://blog.profiq.cz/2012/01/19/automated-installation-and-configuration-of-openam/)